# Create, aggregate and plot signals using various methods for a given symbol using its historical data

Tags: python, object-oriented, inheritance

I am hoping to get some help regarding code arrangement/organization using OOP concepts. My question is whether my usage of class/object selection/declaration and instantiation are sensible and what are the ways to make them more sensible.

Essentially there are 3 classes, and 1 main function that makes use of them.

```
class SigGen(object):

    def __init__(self, bars, method):
        self.bars= bars
        self.method = method
        self.rlzd = get_changes(self.bars) # this is an imported function from another module

    def gen_sig(self, *args):
        self.sig = self.method(args)

    ....maybe more methods will be created later, no other methods right now.
```

**Questions:**

1. Is the use of the `get_changes` function to set `self.rlzd` appropriate during the instantiation?
2. Is the use of `gen_sig` to create "sig" attribute outside of instantiation appropriate?

   Here is the main function:

   ```
   for isym, sym in enumerate(symbol_list):
       bars= get_data_for_symbol(sym)
       for im, m in enumerate(method_list):
           strat = SigGen(sym, bars, m) 
           for iwindow, window in enumerate(windows):
               args = get_args(m, window)
               strat.gen_sig(*args)
               plot.create_sig_plots(strat, iwindow, window)
               df_list.append(strat.sig) 
           sig[m.__name__] = pd.concat(df_list, axis =1) 

           if aggregate_w == 'y':
               for i_agg, agg_method in enumerate(agg_method_list):
                   agg_object = aggregator(signal_df = sig[m.__name__],
                                           rlzd = strat.rlzd,
                                           lookback = lookback_list[i_agg])
                   agg_sig[m.__name__] = agg_method(agg_object) 

                   if plot.running_agg:
                       plot.create_agg_plots( agg_sig[sym][m.__name__], rlzd,  agg_method.__name__, len(windows))
   ```
3. Do I need to create an `agg_object` above (class declaration below)? The only reason I did it is that in the declaration of various methods in `Aggregator` class, I don't have to pass in all the values used in instantiation of the object.

   ```
   class Aggregator(object):
       def __init__(self, signal_df, rebal_freq, realized, lookback=30):
           self.all_signals_df = signal_df
           self.rlzd = realized
           self.lookback = lookback

       def running_perf(self):
           hits= np.sign(self.all_sign_df) == np.sign(self.rlzd) 
           running_performance = pd.rolling_mean(hits, self.lookback)
           agg_sig = pd.DataFrame(self.all_sig_df.lookup(running_performance.index, best_window))
           return agg_sig
   ```